# ASP.net - adding javascript for nested user control inside update panel fails

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have UserControl-B that resides in an UpdatePanel on UserControl-A.  UserControl-A reside in an update panel on default.aspx.  I need to add a jquery event handler for some controls on UserControl-B.

I tried to do this by adding the javascript via the RegisterClientScriptBlock (I also tried RegisterStartScript).  The script is present when UserControl-A is showing and I have not yet launched UserControl-B.  When I do the action that launches UserControl-B the script is not present.

I am adding the script with the following code in UserControl-B:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load()
    Dim sbJS As New StringBuilder()

    sbJS.AppendLine("   $('a[data-toggle=""tab""]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {")
    sbJS.AppendLine("       console.log('in shown.bs.tab');")
    sbJS.AppendLine("   });")

     ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(SomeClass), "myScript", sbJS.ToString(), true)

End Sub
```

In the debugger I see that the UserControl-B.Page_Load() method is called both when UserControl-A is loaded and when UserControl-B is loaded.

Any ideas on why the Javascript does not appear when UserControl-B is loaded?

Also, is there a better way to add this Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: In the code you just copied, you don't use the sbJS at all. I guess after that you would be adding it with the RegisterClientScriptBlock, right? ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(SomeClass), "myScript", sbJS.ToString(), true);

Comment: Sorry about that.  You are correct.  I am performing the registerclientscriptblock call.  I have updated the example.

Comment: Try and add the javascript in the method "Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildren" instead of the Load... sometimes when I have different user controls can give some errors.